# python ImportError: No module named request

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

I am running a python cgi script that makes use of the module urllib.request

I am using Pycharm and when running the script in Pycharm everything is working fine. But when I try to run my script on a local server...

(using following command to start the server)

```
python3 -m http.server --cgi 8000
```

...I get following error:

```
ImportError: No module named request
```

I have checked if I have the module correctly installed.
running

```
sudo -H pip3 install requests
```

gives me the expected "Requirement already satisfied". Also when doing

```
sudo -H pip3 install requests --upgrade
```

I get the expected "Requirement already up-to-date. I have also check if I am using python 3.4 in Pycharm and I am, so this can't be the problem either.

Comment: What is the `import` line that generates the error? Better yet, please copy-paste the **complete** error message and traceback into your question.

Comment: What is the first line of your CGI script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have coded your Python CGI script to require Python3, but you are actually running it with Python2. Change the first line of the script to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```